# SQL: How to show all rows from one table that are not all listed in the 2nd table joined

Tags: sql, join

I am having difficulty getting all the rows to show from the 'Customer' table, as they are not all listed in the 'SalesOrder' table I have joined.

How do I get all the rows to show from the Customer table even if they have a 0 value? Thank you for any suggestions :)

```
SELECT Customer.CID, Customer.Name, 
COUNT (SalesOrder.CID) AS NbrOrders, 
SUM (FullPrice) AS [Total Value of Items]
FROM (Customer
  INNER JOIN SalesOrder
  ON Customer.CID=SalesOrder.CID)
GROUP BY Customer.CID, Customer.Name;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a left join. This will show values from second table which dont have corresponding data in first table.

Comment: Excellent, you're very helpful - that worked thank you! The results now show the customers with no orders, however, is it possible to show those with with no orders as having $0 in Total Value?

Comment: Use `ISNULL` function

Answer (score 1):

use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN

```
SELECT Customer.CID, Customer.Name, 
COUNT (SalesOrder.CID) AS NbrOrders, 
SUM (FullPrice) AS [Total Value of Items]
FROM Customer
  LEFT JOIN SalesOrder
  ON Customer.CID=SalesOrder.CID
GROUP BY Customer.CID, Customer.Name;
```